# How to rotate the text fragments of a NSTextContainer in a UITextView?

Tags: ios, uitextview, nstextcontainer

I'm using a UITextView and want to change the angle of the text fragments as described in the drawing below.

The **current result** shows my actual way:

`frameText.layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(angle), 0, 0, 1);`

[image]

As described by Ray Wenderlich in his [Text Kit tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/50151/text-kit-tutorial) a TextView is separeated into several classes:

[image]

I know, it is possible to define size and position of a text fragement in a custom `NSTextContainer` e.g. using the

`(CGRect)lineFragmentRectForProposedRect:(CGRect)proposedRect atIndex:(NSUInteger)characterIndex writingDirection:(NSWritingDirection)baseWritingDirection remainingRect:(CGRect *)remainingRect {...}` method.

But I can't find a way to rotate the text fragments directly.
**Does anyone have an idea how to achieve this?**